# getline item returning empty variable

Tags: c++, parsing, text, getline

I'm trying to read in a text file and separate the lines into cities and locations. Everything is working for most of the lines, but for I'm getting a

```
terminate called after throwing and instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
   what(): stoi
Aborted (core dumped)
```

After some investigating, I figured out that it's hanging up on the 2 in Lima, Peru. I could be that the getline function is giving it something it can't handle, but there are instances of exactly the same number in exactly the same position earlier in the document.

```
...
Hobart, Tasmania: 42 52 S 147 19 E
Hong Kong, China: 22 20 N 114 11 E
Iquique, Chile: 20 10 S 70 7 W
Irkutsk, Russia: 52 30 N 104 20 E
Jakarta, Indonesia: 6 16 S 106 48 E
Johannesburg, South Africa: 26 12 S 28 4 E
Kingston, Jamaica: 17 59 N 76 49 W
Kinshasa, Congo: 4 18 S 15 17 E
Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia: 3 8 N 101 42 E
La Paz, Bolivia: 16 27 S 68 22 W
Leeds, England: 53 45 N 1 30 W
Lima, Peru: 12 0 S 77 2 W
Lisbon, Portugal: 38 44 N 9 9 W
Liverpool, England: 53 25 N 3 0 W
London, England: 51 32 N 0 5 W
Lyons, France: 45 45 N 4 50 E
Madrid, Spain: 40 26 N 3 42 W
...
```

Here's the section of the code that I think is throwing the error. I can post more if needed, but I think this is the relevant part.

```
while(is_more_stuff_there(file_to_read))
{
    getline(file_to_read, line);

    // parse city
    index = line.find(':');
    city_name = line.substr(0 , line.find(':'));
    istringstream position_stream(line.substr(index + 2 , line.find(':')));

    cout << city_name << endl;

    // initialize an array to store the parsed values from the position_string
    string position_array[6];
    string item;
    int i = 0;

    // fill the array, split by spaces
    while (getline(position_stream, item, ' '))
    {
        position_array[i] = item;
        i++;
        cout << item << endl;
    }

    cout << position_array[4] << endl;

    // initialize the position variables
    lat_min = stoi(position_array[0]);
    lat_sec = stoi(position_array[1]);
    long_min = stoi(position_array[3]);
    long_sec = stoi(position_array[4]);

    // determine positivity of lats and longs
    if (position_array[2] == "S") { lat_min *= -1; lat_sec *= -1; }
    if (position_array[5] == "E") { long_min *= -1; long_sec *= -1; }   

    vertex city(city_name, lat_min, lat_sec, long_min, long_sec);
    g.add_vertex(city);
}
```

Comment: What does it print if you output `position_array[0]` to `position_array[4]`?

Comment: It will print [12, 0, 77, then throw the error

Comment: I'm not sure what your error is though the following looks wrong: `istringstream position_stream(line.substr(index + 2 , line.find(':')));`.  Note however, that you can much more easily read integers like so: `position_stream >> last_min`.

Comment: Can you explain that a little more. It sounds like what I was trying earlier, but I couldn't get it to work. Note that not all of the needed info are integers.

Comment: The `substr` call looks wrong because the second argument (supposed to be the length of the sub-string to return) is random.  Just leave it out and you'll get the entire string that remains.  To read in the directions (as strings), simply do `string d; position_stream >> d;` like you would do for integers.  It will stop reading at whitespace which should be just what you need.  (Of course you must read the values in the order they appear in the input.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem that I can see with your code is that the second parameter passed to the [`substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) function seems wrong.  It should be the length of the sub-string to extract but that need not coincide with the index of the `:`.  You can simply leave the second parameter out to get the entire remaining sub-string.

```
std::istringstream position_stream(line.substr(index + 2));
```

If you only add 1 to `index`, your code will also parse inputs where there is no space after the colon.

Although not fundamentally wrong, the code could be simplified by using the C++ style extraction operators.  You can read in your four fields directly from the stream.

```
int lat_min, lat_sec, long_min, long_sec;
std::string ns, we;
position_stream >> lat_min >> lat_sec >> ns >> long_min >> long_sec >> we;
```

Then continue processing them with whatever logic is required.

Answer (score 2):

There is a non-printing character in your text file, just before the 2 in question. you could find what exactly it is by using od -x (if you're on a unix box). Or simply remove the line and retype it.